# How to compare json list with another list in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a json response with a list of strings. I want to check if it contains the same elements as some other list (order of those elements isn't important. How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
jsonPath("$.country_codes[*]").findAll.sorted.is(List("DE", "CH", "FR", "IE", "IT", "NL", "RS", "UK", "IN").sorted)
```

but I'm getting error "Cannot resolve symbol sorted". If I don't use 'sorted', it works, but I can't rely on getting the same order of elements from server each time..

Answer (score 0):

Use [transform](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#http-check-transform) to turn your `Seq[String]` into a `Set[String]` or sort it.